# Trouble loading array safely in my angular html template

Tags: arrays, angular, undefined

I have an array that is populated after a `.subscribe` to my API. Console shows it populated as expected. Accessing an element of the array results to an error thrown because of it being undefined

```
<div *ngIf="!invoices || invoices.length === 0">
       No invoices
</div>
<div *ngIf="invoices || async ">
      {{ invoices[0]?.invoice_id || async}}
</div>
```

If I remove the elvis operator my content will load fine however the console will throw errors `InvoicesComponent.html:10 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'invoice_id' of undefined` until the array gets populated from the subscribe function.

The invoices array is initialised in my service

```
 invoices: Array<Invoice> = [];
```

And I populate the array

```
getInvoices(){
   var _invoices = this.invoices;
   if(this.afAuth.user){
      // users/uid/invoices/invoice_id/
      var userRef = this.afs.doc(`users/${this.afAuth.auth.currentUser.uid}`)

 userRef.collection('invoices').get().subscribe(function(querySnapshot) {
        querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
        // doc.data() is never undefined for query doc snapshots
        console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
        _invoices.push({
          'invoice_id': doc.id, 
          'customer_company': doc.data().customer_company, 
          'year_id':doc.data().year_id, 
          'date_created': doc.data().date_created, 
          'date_modified': doc.data().date_modified})
    });
    console.log(_invoices)
});
return _invoices
}
```

Based on the suggestion of trichetriche, an `Invoice class was created

```
import { QueryDocumentSnapshot } from  "@angular/fire/firestore";
import { of } from 'rxjs'

export class Invoice {
    invoice_id: string;
    customer_company: string;
    date_created: string;
    date_modified: string;
    year_id: string;

constructor(invoiceDoc: QueryDocumentSnapshot<any>){
    this.invoice_id = invoiceDoc.id
    this.customer_company = invoiceDoc.data().customer_company
    this.date_created = invoiceDoc.data().date_created
    this.date_modified = invoiceDoc.data().date_modified
    this.year_id = invoiceDoc.data().year_id
}

    toObservable(){
        return of(this)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Original

```html
<div *ngIf="!invoices || invoices.length === 0">
       No invoices
</div>
<div *ngIf="invoices || async ">
      {{ invoices[0]?.invoice_id || async}}
</div>
```

### Edited

```html
<ng-container *ngIf="invoices | async as invoicesSync; else noInvoices">
  <p>{{ invoicesSync[0]?.invoice_id || 'No ID for invoice' }}</p>
</ng-container>
<ng-template #noInvoices>
  <p>No invoices</p>
</ng-template>
```

1 - It's `| async`, not `|| async` : `|` is a pipe, `||` is a fallback to a falsy statement.
2 - There should be a single async in your code, which create a template variable through `as XXX`.
3 - You don't need several conditions. Use a single one with a `then` statement.

Comment: All valid points, thank you. I think I'm having trouble with invoices being an array and not an observable

Comment: They work the same way, but if that bothers you that much, you can simply use an observable for it.

Comment: I wanted to format my data as a JSON based on my Invoice interface, i updated the question to reflect what I did. Can you recommend a way to do this during the subscription to the observable?

Comment: Well you could use a class instead of an interface and use the payload as the argument of the constructor, that would reduce the amount of code and allow you to bind functions to your objects

Comment: that sounds cool, so if I get it, the constructor of my Invoice class takes the payload as an argument like so, new Invoice(my 5 arguments) inside my getInvoices method. How are these objects returned as an observable though?

Comment: No, more like `new Invoice(doc.data())`, and the constructor checks for common properties (if they don't exist the simply equate to undefined so it's even safe)

Comment: After that you can transform your object to an observable if needed, but both are independants

Comment: when you say the "constructor checks for common properties" is this what you meant: (see edited answer for better formatting)

Comment: Yes exactly. Now if the property doesn't exist, it simply will be undefined, meaning you can do classes likes that for any other objects of your choosing

Comment: You can also create a function `toObservable` that simply do `return of(this)` effectively creating an observable for your object (not that useful but if you need it ...)

Comment: Cool, I get it. I'm not ecstatic about observables, I just want to make sure my template loads my array (or observable) in good time so i don't get the undefined errors. That's why I wanted to return the payload as an observable because I expect that with the async pipe this will be solved?

Comment: Well no, using ngIf will resolve that. Observables with async just have the advantage of triggering the change detection when the value changes.

Comment: The thing is using ngIf didn't solve it, it never went to the "else" for when the array had been populated

Answer (score 0):

i think you are using the Async pipe in wrong way .

you can passe Observable directly to template and the code will like this :

```
   <div *ngIf="invoices|async as invoicesList; else noInvoices">
     {{ invoicesList[0]?.invoice_id}}
   </div>
   <ng-template #noInvoices>
     <div  >
       No invoices
     </div>
   </ng-template>
```

Comment: indeed I was, still doesn't work, because invoices is an array and not an observable. I will see how I can make it into an observable

Answer (score 0):

Right so after some research it seems that I was better off subscribing to an observable and dealing with the data as it arrives from my API with the async pipe.

So my final functions look kind of like this:

```js
ngOnInit() {
    this.observableInvoices = this.auth.getObservableInvoices().pipe(map( 
      (data) => data));
    console.log(this.observableInvoices)
    }
```

```html
<li *ngFor="let invoice of observableInvoices | async; index as i">
```

```js
  getObservableInvoices(): Observable<any> {
    this.observable_invoices = this.afs
      .collection(`users/${this.afAuth.auth.currentUser.uid}/invoices`)
      .valueChanges() as Observable<any[]>;
    return this.observable_invoices;
  }
```